# Symfony 1.4 chang an embedded form in AdminGenerator-module / Find Query

Tags: mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I added two fields to a table, which is used as an embedded form in an admin-generator-module. I created the widgets and changed the templates. I also put the fields in generator.yml, changed schema.yml and executed doctrine:build --all-classes and cc.

Although the fields do appear and the entered data is saved to the MySQL-DB, the data is **not shown** in the textfields, as the new fields are not part of the MySQL-Query (which goes for every single of the old fields).

I did a grep over the whole application - everything is done exactly the same way as it is for the old fields.

How / where is the MySQL-Query created or cached and how can I (force SF to) change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out, what happened...
The query used to be cached by APC. Calling

```
  apc_clear_cache();
  apc_clear_cache('user');
  apc_clear_cache('opcode');
```

in preExecute() solved the problem. gosh.....